# How can I embed buttons inside a Link tag that don't forward to the Links destination?

Tags: reactjs, twitter, hyperlink, react-router-dom

[image: tweet example]

In my react project I'm trying to create a Tweet-like component. In a tweet, as shown above, if you press the background you will be forwarded to the tweet's individual view. But, if you press one of the buttons below (Like, Retweet, etc), the button will initiate their own action. So in my app I'm creating a Card component (my "tweet") that is surrounded in a Link tag. But, if I press the "like" button inside the card component, it initiates its action AND forwards me to the "tweet's" individual view. The button is a child of the Card component, but ideally if I press the button I should stay on the current page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: to be clear, the buttons are children of the <Link>, but do not forward upon click.

Answer (score 0):

answer: for the child links, include: `onClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation()`